# Measure Theory Absolute Continuity

Tags: measure-theory

Qualifying Exam Practice.

Let $p>0$ and define $\nu(E) = \int_E x^p d \lambda(x)$, $E \in \mathcal{B}[1,\infty)$. Show that $\nu << \lambda$, but the limit $\lim_{\lambda(E) \rightarrow 0} |\nu(E)|$ is not zero.

I believe $\nu << \lambda$ can be shown using the absolute continuity of the Lebesgue integral. I am unclear about the second part.

Comment: By $\mu$, do you mean $\lambda$?

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The second part says that you can find sets $E$ with very small Lebesgue measure, yet such that the integral of $x^p$ over the set $E$ is not very small. So $E$ should be located someplace where $x^p$ is big. Try $E=[n,n+1]$ for large $n$.